Made promise to a deity in childhood then broke it, should I take it seriously?
Back when I was 12-13 years old , I almost got into big trouble in school. I was very tensed and in crisis made a cry to Lord Vishnu that I will leave non vegetarian food if I got out of trouble which I did but I am still a Non-vegetarian. What to do? What to make out of it?

What you should consider seriously is the rajasic and tamasic effects on the mind due to meat consumption as it'd be practically impossible to control lust and concentrate the mind in any serious spiritual practice to liberate the soul. Another is the consequences of having to personally undergo the sufferings faced by the animals. There's plenty of fruits and vegetables available on earth currently...

@dasdasanudasah I am more curious about consequences of broken oath/promise to supreme Vishnu

One is not to make an oath in front of a deity as a general guideline. I believe they're rectified the moment one prays to Him sincerely.
